# Apns device registration azure mobile service ios with .net back end error

Tags: ios, .net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

Hi ive been having major issues with this for some reason and cant work out why.

Im registering for device registrations :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application

didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
MSClient *client = self.authService.client;
[client.push registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
if (error != nil) {
NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
}
}];
}
```

in the filter response method which looks like this:

```
- (void) filterResponse: (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response
                forData: (NSData *) data
              withError: (NSError *) error
             forRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request
                 onNext:(MSFilterNextBlock) onNext
             onResponse: (MSFilterResponseBlock) onResponse{
 **code omitted **
}
```

i get back in the reponse:

> { URL:
>   https://hiddenAppName-mobile-app.azure-mobile.net/push/registrations%3FdeviceId=0F165A3BD554E4F4FCB8E412B537F2FE10B08FE1E2D1C168AE9EBE8A6DC15CA9&platform=apns
>   } { status code: 200, headers { "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>   "Content-Encoding" = gzip; "Content-Length" = 483; "Content-Type" =
>   "application/json; charset=utf-8"; Date = "Thu, 03 Sep 2015 21:11:01
>   GMT"; Expires = 0; Pragma = "no-cache"; Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>   "Set-Cookie" =
>   "ARRAffinity=6400fd48b4ba8e8bea4813afbd16c1ff61bacfd0d259c7c36e529f742a8de958;Path=/;Domain=hiddenAppName-mobile-app.azure-mobile.net";
>   Vary = "Accept-Encoding"; "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } }

and the data is:

> [{"platform":"apns","deviceId":"0F165A3BD554E4F4FCB8E412B537F2FE10B08FE1E2D1C168AE9EBE8A6DC15CA9","registrationId":"3293417219461121655-5315545091225715647-20","tags":["CCE40A1696B14DADA2F005D554F970F6"],"templateName":null,"templateBody":null,"headers":{},"expiration":"2015-11-14T22:29:07.896Z"},{"platform":"apns","deviceId":"0F165A3BD554E4F4FCB8E412B537F2FE10B08FE1E2D1C168AE9EBE8A6DC15CA9","registrationId":"6230917652908957715-607108047627745508-20","tags":["13E1958EDF1D43AD8B5D9F61CF1203C8"],"templateName":null,"templateBody":null,"headers":{},"expiration":"2015-11-17T20:58:32.505Z"}]

when the onResponse callback is called from the the filterResponse method (above) the app crashes a few calls down in [MSLocalStorage commitDefaultsWithStorageVersion]
with this error:

> Property list invalid for format: 200 (property list dictionaries may
>   only have keys which are CFStrings, not 'CFNull') 2015-09-03
>   22:18:58.778 hiddenAppName[2399:1160388] Attempt to set a
>   non-property-list object { "" =
>   "6230917652908957715-607108047627745508-20"; } as an
>   NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key
>   hiddenAppName-mobile-app.azure-mobile.net-registrations 2015-09-03
>   22:18:58.779 hiddenAppName[2399:1160388] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to
>   insert non-property list object { "" =
>   "6230917652908957715-607108047627745508-20"; } for key
>   hiddenAppName-mobile-app.azure-mobile.net-registrations'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x1829e022c 0x1946ac0e4 0x1829e016c 0x182a19fb4 0x18296c870
>   0x18296b850 0x182a1a2b0 0x182a19848 0x182a1d0d8 0x18380a960
>   0x10012ec00 0x10012e748 0x10011b78c 0x100121474 0x10007bce4
>   0x10007b734 0x10011ee7c 0x18245d1e8 0x18245d178 0x18245d2f4
>   0x18232fdfc 0x1823fa120 0x18231befc 0x1828c097c 0x18231bda8
>   0x18231bc5c 0x18231ba88 0x182997f8c 0x182997230 0x1829952e0
>   0x1828c0f74 0x18c31b6fc 0x1874c2d94 0x10001762c 0x194d56a08)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Any ideas why this is anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with handling null template names that is now fixed in 2.2.1.  If you update to that version you should be good to go.  (fix: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/commit/9347390)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response! Since changing this it has stopped crashing but now i receive no push notifications. I have a production cert on the server(ive tried the sandbox one aswell with a dev cert) and am registering devices (event though they disappear after one push) the mobile service says the message the message was sent to the apns but it never arrives anymore. Is there more to this than just the upgrade? should it have been sending back a template? I assume at some point i was receiving template as it didn't crash for three or four days then all of the sudden started.

Comment: Its probably a cert issue I'm going to go through the whole process again step by step but i don't understand what changed ..... its very frustrating